# Kotlin: Sorting | Location of swap operation

Tags: sorting, kotlin, quicksort, software-design

I'm implementing the Quicksort algorithm in Kotlin. For that, I created an interface, *ISort*, with a type parameter and a single function, *sort*. For sorting, I need the swap operation. I was wondering what the best location of this swap function is. My ideas:

1) Unfortunately, in Kotlin one cannot make interface function protected. Thus, every class could see the swap in its implementations and that's not too nice (although it's not too bad either, I agree).

2) Putting it in the QuickSort implementation is even worse because there might be several implementations of the ISort interface that need a swap function.

3) My next thought was to create a singleton object but Kotlin permits objects with type parameters.

Here is the interface definition:

```
interface ISort<T> {
  fun sort(toSort: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T>
  // 1) Putting swap here has a too high visibility
}
```

And here is the skeleton of the QuickSort class:

```
class QuickSort<T> : ISort<T> {
  override fun sort(toSort: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> {
    doQuickSort(toSort) // Internally uses swap
    return toSort
  }
  // 2) Putting swap here might lead to code duplication of swap
}
```

So, from a software engineering perspective what would be the best place / location for the swap operation.

Comment: Perhaps if you include some code snippets, it will become a bit clearer.

Comment: I don't see why you need the swap function. Is `val temp = a; a = b; b = temp` not enough?

Comment: I updated my question and added some code. @Naetmul: I know how to implemenet the swap but am know sure where its best location is.

Comment: I think the quicksort should be a top-level generic function. I don't see any merit to create an interface and a class. "Quicksort" is a utility function, which needs not follow the OOP paradigm. The swap function should be top-level `private`, which means that it is private to the file it's declared in (https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html)

Comment: Instead, you can create an `object QuickSort` which contains both the generic public `sort()` and the generic private `swap()`, but using an object as a namespace is not recommended(https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/2198/5) although this is a popular way in Scala.

Comment: @Naetmul 'sort' is a utility function, which can use different strategies. I think it's perfectly fine to make this OOP, even if it's a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Top level functions

In a file `sort.kt` or so,

```
package abc.def.sort


fun <T> quicksort(list: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> {
    ...
}

// invisible in other files, but visibie in "sort.kt"
private fun <T> swap(...) {
    ...
}
```

To use the `swap` function in other sorts, you will need to define other sort functions in the same file. (Or copy the `swap` function many times.)

This is recommended for very simple functions.

## Object as a namespace

This is similar to the method above, but more OOP-ish than the previous one.

```
object QuickSort {
    fun <T> sort(list: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> {
        ...
    }

    private fun <T> swap(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

or

```
object Sorts {
    fun <T> quicksort(list: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> {
        ...
    }

    // add other sort methods...

    private fun <T> swap(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, this is not recommended in Kotlin ([Best practices for top-level declarations](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/best-practices-for-top-level-declarations/2198/5)).

## Combination of abstract class and object

The `swap` function can be reused for other sorts in this way.

```
abstract class Sort {
    abstract fun <T> sort(list: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T>

    protected fun <T> swap(...) {
        ...
    }
}

object QuickSort : Sort() {
    override fun <T> sort(list: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> {
        ...
    }
}
```

I think [making the type parameter `T` be a class type parameter, not a function type parameter] will make the problem unnecessarily more complex because you will have to create a class instance for each time you use different type `T`.

Comment: How embarassing of me not to have thought of using an abstract class... Thank you very much